# Reference a C# file that is within the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, tags

I am creating an asp.net page that will call some C# code.

The method I am trying to call is called CheckForMachineOfflineAlert()

and is in the class AlertEngine,

which is in the file alertengine,

which is in the folder GTS.

In normal C# code, the method would be called by the following:

```
AlertEngine oDM = new AlertEngine();    
oDM.CheckForMachineOfflineAlert();
```

I think i need some tags at the top of the page to reference the correct class, but I can t find the correct syntax. The best I have so far is:

```
<%@ Page Language    = "C#"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "GTS" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.AlertEngine" %>

<%
    AlertEngine oDM = new AlertEngine();    
    oDM.CheckForMachineOfflineAlert();
%>
```

But this is incorrect.

The aim is to launch this page in a browser and have it execute the C# code.

Comment: What namespace is the `AlertEngine` class defined in?

Comment: System.AlertEngine? Isn't it giving you error?

Comment: @Codeek Yes it is, I am trying to find out the correct way to achieve this

Comment: Why not try GTS.AlertEngine oDM = new GTS.AlertEngine(); after importing GTS?

Comment: Daft question, why not just put it in the code-behind, hinged off Page_Load? It's best to avoid anything directly non-display related off the aspx page.

Comment: @Codeek That did not work

Comment: What namespace is `AlertEngine` in, `System.AlertEngine` does not look right. Also as @HugoYates says, put it in the code behind.

Comment: Probaboly your GTS itself is in different location than working directory or parent directory. try using a sample class of same directory ans see if works, then progress by putting it in folder and so on

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language    = "C#"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "GTS" %>

<%
    AlertEngine oDM = new AlertEngine(); 
    oDM.CheckForMachineOfflineAlert();
%>
```